# Pygame not blitting image,instead spitting out type error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

So I was watching this tutorial online about pygame as I am extremely new to pygame. So what he did was create a player() function and then blit it. So I did the same. For him, he gets it perfectly blitted, but for me, I get a type error. The only thing different between his code and mine is the dimensions of the window and player class and colours. I tried searching it here in stack overflow, but the only relevant question was unanswered. Not sure what went wrong.

full error:

```
/home/Command Blocks/Desktop/venv/bin/python "/home/CommandBlocks/Desktop/CLASS_/Studies/Computer/python/practice/space shooter/main.py"
pygame 2.0.2 (SDL 2.0.16, Python 3.9.5)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/Command Blocks/Desktop/CLASS_/Studies/Computer/python/practice/space shooter/main.py", line 33, in <module>
    player()
  File "/home/Command Blocks/Desktop/CLASS_/Studies/Computer/python/practice/space shooter/main.py", line 20, in player
    screen.blit(player, (playerX, playerY))
TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not function

Process finished with exit code 1
```

full code:

```
import pygame

#Initialize pygame module
pygame.init()

#Create Screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1000, 600))

#Title and Icon
pygame.display.set_caption("Jungle Invader")
icon = pygame.image.load('fox-sitting.png')
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

# Player
player = pygame.image.load('cat.png')
playerX = 300
playerY = 500

def player():
    screen.blit(player, (playerX, playerY))


#Main loop
running = True
while running:
    pygame.display.update()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    screen.fill((244, 232, 255))
    player()
```

Comment: You have used the name `player` twice. It is the surface returned by `pygame.image.load('cat.png')` and the function that blits to the screen.

Comment: ... rename the `player` function: `drawPlayer`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention the change of player variable name, the tutorial person had used a big name so I shortened it down. Thanks by the way @Rabbid76

Comment: and @ChrisOram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used the name player twice. It is the surface returned by `pygame.image.load('cat.png')` and the function that `blits` to the screen. Rename the `player` function to `drawPlayer`

Comment: Well I got it clarified weeks ago, but yours is still the correct answer.